# Add background to navbar-brand in Twitter Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to change background color on brand image in navbar ?
I have tried many times, using flex-row, like

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">

      <div>
           company image with text
      </div>

      <div id='right'>
          ... Navbar
      </div

</div>
```

Those method is not worked in mobile view, especially because toggle-navbar being weird.

---

For simplicity, this is my plain bootstrap 4 navbar in codepen :

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ahmadfadlydziljalal/pen/poaKmNd)

---

But, We need something like this:

From
[image: Navbar]
to :
[image: Image of Navbar]

Comment: Anyone ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: use css to change the background however you want, and if that mess up things in mobile view you might have to use media query.